# Why increasing parallel degree increases query time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 8 million rows.

I created exactly same table without any index,pk,fk and tried to insert all records from table activity to temp_activity.

```
alter session enable parallel dml;
alter table activity_temp nologging

insert into  temp_activity m
  select /*+ APPEND PARALLEL (i) */
   t.*
    from activity t
```

My results are

```
i=1 -> 168 sec
i=2 -> 197 sec
i=3 -> 208 sec
i=10 -> 268 sec
without  /*APPEND PARALEL*/ hint -> +10 min
```

Question is self explanatory: What is the problem of compiler?

Comment: How many cores does your server have?   What other activity is going on?  Have you tried it with just `/*+ APPEND */` hint?

Comment: Not sure why you need to have both the hints. Parallel is always a direct path, if you go parallel, you will be appending. Some good read https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1211797200346279484

Comment: @APC Machine has 2 core.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I'm just learning things (=

Comment: @AliArdaOrhan No problem mate. I tried to point few things, see my answer.

Comment: is you query really so simple? please post  exec plan.

Comment: @LalitKumarB are you sure that parallel is always direct? there are various reasons for not using direct path load, like constraints, triggers, ...

Comment: i can't write an entire book about it in the comments. So, I posted a supporting link to AskTom where it is beautifully address by T.Kyte.

Answer (score 2):

> select /*+ APPEND PARALLEL (i) */

Makes no sense to me. Why would yo have an `APPEND` hint in the SELECT?

I think you want to do like this:

```
alter session enable parallel dml;
insert /*+ append parallel(i) */ into temp_activity select * from activity;
```

Also, note that parallel is always a direct path, if you go parallel, you will be appending. And that a parallel insert will take an exclusive lock on the table. Because, you cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel.

A good read for you https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1211797200346279484

And regarding **Types of Parallelism**, everything is documented. Read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel003.htm#i1006712